# "Record already in use" when trying to add A record to custom Firebase site

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm currently connecting a custom site to Firebase hosting.

Firebase has given me the following error:

```
We expected these A records
    Host: my.app
    Values:
        151.xxx.1.xxx
        151.xxx.85.xxx
We found these A records
    Host: my.app
    Values:
        151.xxx.1.xxx

Add these A records to your domain by visiting your DNS provider or registrar. 

Your site will show a security certificate warning for a few hours, until the certificate has been provisioned.

Record type Host    Value
A
my.app 
151.xxx.1.xxx
A
my.app 
151.xxx.85.xxx
```

I've already added the first A record in my Google Domains backend (`151.xxx.1.xxx`), but when I try to add the second (`151.xxx.85.xxx`) I get this error: `Record already in use`.

I'm getting this error because the host value is the exact same (`@` or `my.app`).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@Zorgan

Try clicking `edit` button, then click the `+` sign next to the input field

check the attached image. Hope that helps.

update: oh boy they're sunsetting their service, moving the assets to Squarespace :(

[image: adding record]

Comment: I never noticed that little `+` beside the input field.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Corin now that google domains is sold to another company :(.